# Approach to adding persistence code in Symfony when not using Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, dao

I am interested in learning about best practices for persistence code in Symfony2 when not using an ORM and not having objects represent my table rows.

One way would be to create a model / dao directory and store classes with wrapper methods (e.g. getPost($id), addPost($title, $content) for a blog post). Then access these methods inside the service class which has similarly named methods as getPost($id) etc. which might just be calling the wrapper methods in the model / dao classes or doing a bit more work (preprocessing data to send to db, postprocessing data received from db).

Do you think this is a reasonable approach or is there something better you can think of? Thanks.

Comment: Google: DataMapper. Entities. Repositories. Value Objects. Then when you've built what you need with good SoC, you'll find that you might as well have just used an ORM :P

Comment: For inspiration: you can also use [Doctrine/SkeletonMapper](https://github.com/doctrine/skeleton-mapper/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/SkeletonMapper). These are basically only interfaces that uses Doctrine. Implementation depends on you.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some code? It's easier to understand your intentions.

Comment: For PHP Request/Response applications, having a service layer which duplicates methods in some sort of dao layer seems like overkill.  I often use arrays for data objects and query using Doctrine's DBAL connection object.  Are you maybe thinking about active records? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent